# Atlasssian Crucible through AWS ELB with HTTPS

Tags: nginx, https, amazon-elb, atlassian-crucible

I've recently setup a Crucible instances in AWS connected via a HTTPS ELB. I have a nginx reverse proxy setup on the instance as well to redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS.

This partially works. However Crucible itself doesn't know it's running over HTTPS so serves up mixed content, and ajax queries often break due to HTTP -> HTTPS conflicts.

I've found documentation for installing a certificate in Crucible directly...

https://confluence.atlassian.com/fisheye/fisheye-ssl-configuration-298976938.html

However I'd really rather not have to do it this way. I want to have the HTTPS terminated at the ELB, to make it easier to manage centrally through AWS.

I've also found documentation for using Crucible through a reverse proxy...

https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/proxying-atlassian-server-applications-with-apache-http-server-mod_proxy_http-806032611.html

However this doesn't specifically deal with HTTPS.

All I really need is a way to ensure that Crucible doesn't serve up content with hard coded internal HTTP references. It needs to either leave off the protocol, or set HTTPS for the links.

Answer (score 1):

Setting up the reverse proxy configuration should help accomplish this. Under `Administration >> Global Settings >> Server >> Web Server` set the following:

`Proxy scheme: https
Proxy host: elb.hostname.com
Proxy port: 443`

And restart Crucible.

Answer (score 1):

Making configuration on UI is one way. You can also change config.xml in $FISHEYE_HOME:

```
<web-server site-url="https://your-public-crucible-url">
  <http bind=":8060" proxy-host=“your-public-crucible-url" proxy-port="443" proxy-scheme="https"/>
</web-server>
```

Make sure to shutdown FishEye/Crucible before making this change.

AFAIK, this configuration is the only way to tell internal Jetty of FishEye/Crucible to be aware of the reversed proxy in front of them.